# clearTimeout not working - Tried many variations

Tags: javascript, setinterval, cleartimeout

I have an issue with the clearTimeout function. Both conditions are working but The timeout refuses to clear...... any help is welcome. The time is 300 miliseconds = params.speed.

**NOTE: The method is totally functional and working. The only issue I am having is clearing the setTimeout. It creates a bug where new non-timeout toasters are having the old setTimeout apply.

Meaning if I click the non-time-out button within 3 seconds after clicking the timeout button, the old setTimeout is still applying to the next toaster.

```
        // Beginning of function - line below contains the options for the 
        // toaster method:
        // Invoke via - onclick(e, {text: 'This is an alert with a TIMER', 
        // timer:true, speed: 3500, color: 'dark'})

        toaster: function(e, params = {}) {

            // Set defaults for params.object options
            var setDefaults = function () {
                if (e == null) {
                    e = this.event;
                };
                if (params.speed == null) {
                    params.speed = 3500;
                };
                if (params.timer == null) {
                    params.timer = false;
                };
                if (params.color == null) {
                    params.color = 'light';
                };
                if (params.text == null) {
                    params.text = 'This is a default warning'
                };
            }();

          //Apply timer function
          timerOn(params.speed); // params.speed = 4500
          var timing; // Variable set outside of the timerOn() function

          function timerOn () {

                if (params.timer) {
                    timing = setTimeout(function(){
                        el[0].classList.remove('show-toaster');
                        console.log('happening');
                    }, params.speed);  
                } else {
                    clearTimeout(timing);
                    console.log('just cleared timing variable');
                } 

            } // timerOn ends
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How could I make it more minimal and complete?

Comment: When you call `timerOn` twice with `params.timer` set you loose the reference to the first timer. That might ve a problem

Comment: Are you changing `timing` anywhere else? Perhaps you have another function that is overwriting that variable.

Comment: Thanks @JonasW. - just curious, where am I calling timerOn twice? Do you mean the conditional argument. RE: params.timer only represents an integer value of 3000.

Comment: No @Paulpro - Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: If params.timer is always going to be 3000, at what point are you going to call clearTimeout.?

Comment: If `params.timer` is `3000` every time you call `timerOn`, then you will only add timers and won't ever remove them. `3000` is truthy so the `if` block will always execute and the `else` block never will.

Comment: Hi @Paulpro, nice idea, but I have tested with consoles and both sides of the conditional are functioning as they should. params.timer is an argument the containing function.

Comment: @bubbaShrimp But you said "params.timer only represents an integer value of 3000" in a comment. Is it every anything else that is falsy, like `0`, `false` or `undefined`?

Comment: @Paulpro params timer is either an integer value or false

Comment: So when do you set it false after starting,.. `How could I make it more minimal and complete?`  Making your code into a snippet would really help here.  ClearTimeout certainly works, so there is a bug somewhere else here.

Comment: @bubbaShrimp Then I am afraid Ele is correct. You need to make your example more complete by posting enough code to reproduce the problem, so that there is enough context for someone to help you. Post ***just*** enough code to reproduce it, not more, so that you don't lose the minimal aspect of the MCVE either. While reducing your code down to just the amount you need to reproduce the problem, you will probably end up figuring out the cause of the bug yourself and then you can post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Comment: There are different buttons calling the same function. One passes a param of 3000 milliseconds = param.timer. The non timed removal button posts false = param.timer. The logic is fine, but the timeout will not clear

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks. Yes true, was trying to avoid too much code, will try to add more context

Comment: `The logic is fine`  Obviously not, or you wouldn't be having problems. :)

Comment: @Keith logic meaning conditional is working as it should, nice joke though

Comment: `timerOn(params.speed);` Your timerOn function takes no arguments, the `params.speed` is meaningless.

Comment: Your `timing` var is inside a closure, it will never equal the same timer as another one you created,.   So it would be impossible for you to clear this timer,.  it needs to be outside the closure.

Comment: @Keith thanks for the ideas. timingOn() has an argument of 4500. The closure may be it, but I have timing as a variable outside of the function?

Comment: Still confused here, at one point are you calling `timerOn` when `params.timer` is false.  Nowhere in the code you posted are you doing this.

Comment: Are you trying to clear the timeout using `toaster` with params timer = false, if so that won't work, because of the closure part I mentioned.  The instance of timer var will be a new one with a value of undefined..

Comment: Hi Keith See invoke via comment at top of screen. Options contain true for params.timer.  Thanks for the idea though

Comment: Invoke what?, how, when.. If your second button is calling toater with params timer = false, it won't work.   This is because the `var timer` is a new var each time you call toater, as such doing clearTimeout on it won't do anything.

Comment: @Keith, ok I'm with you on "This is because the var timer is a new var each time you call toaster."........ So how do I fix that?

Comment: Hi @Keith also, params.timer = false should clear the 'timing' vars setTimeOut? That is what the if/else is for, and the 'timing' var is also being declared in a higher scope above the timingOn function. I don't think the timer **property** has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: `higher scope above the timingOn`  But it needs to be a higher scope than your `toaster` function,..  I'll post a simple example of what your doing, understanding this will hopefully help you understand your problem.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for that, still unsure how another step up the scope ladder will solve this. Will be happy to see it though if it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we have here I believe is a problem of scope,.

Let's say we have a function `test`, and when we call it with `true` we save the word hello into a var called x.  If we then call said function again with false we want it to console.log the value of x, hopefully been the word hello.

We could create function like this->

```
function test(b) { var x; if (b) x = "hello"; else console.log(x); }
test(true); 
test(false);  //prints undefined
```

Now the above based on what the OP has said, is kind of what he's doing with the toaster function.  Problem is the above will end up printing `undefined`

So how do we fix,.  All we have to do is move the `var x` declaration so it covers the function `test`, this will then make the `var x` scope global to this instance of test.  IOW: every time we call test we want it to see the same instance of `x`..

So here is the fixed version.

```
var x; function test(b) { if (b) x = "hello"; else console.log(x); }  
test(true); 
test(false);  //prints hello
```

This as expected will print the word `hello`..

Now if you think of the function `test` been the `toaster` function, and the `var x` been the `timer` var, you can see how the `timer` var will end up been undefined the next time you call `toaster`..

Comment: This is definitely the issue.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info @Keith . So, being that the 'timing' var from the toaster method is not in local timerOn() scope, what do I do?

Comment: I moved the 'timing' var to a higher scope than *the toaster method* (which contained many internal functions). Like Keith said, a higher scope would and **did** solve the issue.  

The 'timing' var had to go to a higher scope due to it's changing value _containing on occasion the setTimeout_. Also a scope *higher than the surrounding internal functions.*

Definitely a new one for me. The example code in the problem showed that the 'timing' variable had been lifted to a higher scope....though not high enough. Thanks to @Keith and all others for your help.

Comment: @bubbaShrimp Just to clarify your understanding. The issue was that `timing` was declared inside `toaster` so every call to toaster created a new variable called `timing`. In fact each call to toaster also creates a new function called `timerOn`. Each time you called `timerOn` you were calling a different newly created function that has it's own scope chain (including its own `timing` variable) separate from any other identical looking function called `timerOn` that was created by previous calls to `toaster`.

Comment: @bubbaShrimp Moving the declaration of `timing` outside `toaster` means that each call to `toaster` doesn't create a new `timing` variable anymore. Rather, they all share the higher scoped `timing`. Thus, subsequent calls have access to the `timing` var that a previous call set and is able to clear the interval.

Comment: @bubbaShrimp There is still a new copy of the function `timerOn` being created each time `toaster` is called, since that function declaration is inside `toaster` still, but each function called `timerOn` has to look farther up the scope chain to outside `toaster` to find `timing` now so they all share the same `timing`.

Answer (score 0):

You code is not enough to understand where is error, and what you realy want to do. But i think my code will help you to understand where you was wrong.

```js
var timing;
var params = {
  timer: true,
  speed: 3000
};

function timerToggle() {
  clearTimeout(timing);
  if (params.timer) {
    timing = setTimeout(function() {
      alert("timer works");
    }, params.speed);
  }
}    

timerToggle();

$("button").on("click", function() {
  params.timer = false;
  timerToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me or wait 3 sec</button>
```

Comment: This is good, but also have tried. I have placed the cleartimeout where you suggest. And have also used a one option conditional, like your code. Still does not fix the setTimeout not being cleared.

Comment: `clearTimeout(timing);` is calling every time when you call `timerToggle`. And it clear the timeout every time. I think you call your function too late. Increase your speed x10 to have a time to thnik where your code is wrong.

Comment: @bubbaShrimp  Also this is a working snippet, in what way is this not working the way you expect,..  If you click the run code snippet above and wait 3 seconds you will get a dialog box, but if instead you click the `click me or wait 3 sec` the dialog box won't appear, proving `clearTimeout` did what it said on the tin.

Comment: Sure thing @Keith I will have a good look. clearTimeout has never been an issue before. In this context, I have had issues. Wondering if it someting to do with gulp, dom memory or even the event listeners I am using